# Oracle number precision datatype performance impact

Tags: oracle

Does number size affect to speed of inserting, updating, ...(DML operations) rows?
If i use number(20) instead of number(6), does it impact performance?

Comment: if you have any useful article, please write on comment

Comment: The size of the column constraint (scale/precision) shouldn't matter; and the size of the number value itself is unlikely to be measurably significant. Do you have a reason to think either does make a difference?

Comment: Somewhat surprised to see this got migrated. `[sqldatatypes]` is a recognised tag on StackOverflow so this question was on topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The precision and scale of a number column is a matter for business rules and data modelling. If a number can have values in the trillions don't declare it as `number(6)`.The general cases seem to be

- leave number columns without further definition - `number`
- enforce integer columns e.g. `number(20,0)` or less commonly `integer`
- for cases where it really matters (e.g. monetary values) specify scale and precision e.g. `number(15,2)`

Then there are the specialized edge cases for `binary_float` and `binary_double`. If you are doing heavy-duty calculations there are definite performance benefits from choosing these data types (at the price of losing some exactitude). But if you're using regular `number` columns just choose the precision and scale you need for the business rules, and don't sweat on performance.

> if i define as a number without precision, how it works? what would be default precision?

If we don't define `number` further there is no default precision. We can store any number from `0.0000000000000000000000000000000000001` to `99999999999999999999999999999999999999`.

Comment: if i define as a number without precision, how it works? what would be default precision?

Comment: If a precision is not specified, the column stores values as given